# Transform an input with "month year" to "month/year" in R

Tags: r, excel, date, date-format, yearmonth

If a time-related information is read as "Jun 2008". Are there any convenient approaches to transform it into date format in R or Excel, i.e., 06/2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel the following formula will do the trick:

```
=TEXT(A1,"mm/yyyy")
```